# 301 redirect htaccess nested path

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to redirect about page to home page:

```
Redirect 301 /about http://example.com
```

And it works, but it also redirects pages like `/about/contact` (so it becomes `http://example.com/contact`). Is there any way to redirect just `/about` page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`RedirectMatch`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch) directive here because it allows to specify a regular expression. Then use the `$` sign express that no further character can follow:

```
RedirectMatch 301 \/about$ http://example.com
```

Also I would optionally include the `/` at the end:

```
RedirectMatch 301 \/about\/?$ http://example.com
```

Comment: For some reason, it doesn't work. With your code it redirects to home page only when I manually type in url /about$